# Replacing HTML but saving the word sticking at the end

Tags: python, dataframe, data-cleaning, python-re

I was working with text data, I want to remove anything HTML code that is things with "<" and ">".
For example

**<< HTML > < p style="text-align:justify" >Labour Solutions Australia (LSA) is a national labour hire and sourcing  `**

So I use the following code

```
def remove_html(s):
    
    s = re.sub('[^\S]*<[^\S]*', "", s)
    s = re.sub('[^\S]*>[^\S]*', "", s)
    return s
```

With the execution of the code we get the following result

**Solutions Australia LSA is a national labour hire and sourcing**

I don't want to remove the word Labour but it get remove as it's stick with '>'. Is there any way I can save it? Please suggest

Comment: As usual, note that it's extremely hard to impossible to parse HTML with regex in *general case*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```python
import re
def remove_html(data):
    return re.sub('<[^>]+>', '', data).strip()

test_case = '< HTML > < p style="text-align:justify" >Labour Solutions Australia (LSA) is a national labour hire and sourcing'
print(remove_html(test_case))
```

**Output:**

Labour Solutions Australia (LSA) is a national labour hire and sourcing